# React onClick multiple handler functions issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two handler functions for an onClick event on a button. Basically they do the same thing but one is incrementing an element (passed as a parameter) in the state array while the other is decrementing (but not the same variable). Say I have an array of two elements. I want the first element to be incremented and the second element to be decremented (`array[0]++ array[1]--`).

```
HandleIncrement = instrumentUp => {
  // create a shallow copy of the array
  const tempCount = [...this.state.instrumentCount];
  // increment the desired instrument
  tempCount[instrumentUp] += 1;
  // update the state
  this.setState({
    instrumentCount: tempCount
  });
};

HandleDecrement = instrumentDown => {
  // create a shallow copy of the array
  const tempCount = [...this.state.instrumentCount];
  // decrement the desired instrument
  tempCount[instrumentDown] -= 1;
  // update the state
  this.setState({
    instrumentCount: tempCount
  });
};
```

I also have a button where these two methods are executed.

```
 onClick = {() => {
     this.HandleIncrement(0);
     this.HandleDecrmenet(1);
   }
 }
```

The output is not desired. If this was the `array = [0 1]`, I wish the output to be `[1 0]` however the 
the output is `[0 0]`. I think this is because of these two functions being executed at the same time and so when they `setState`, `HandleDecrement` didn't use the updated state.

Should I be using something like `async` or `await`?

Comment: You cannot `await` state changes because they get processed internally. The recommended solution to your problem is to write an additional function that handles both changes (but calls `setState` only once). Clarity's suggestion, if coded properly, will work though: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-tkw6o

Comment: This has worked thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I found a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

`setState(updater[, callback])` is an async function:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

You can execute a function after setState is finishing using the second param callback like:

```
this.setState({
    instrumentCount: tempCount
}, () => {
    this.HandleDecrmenet(1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this

```
handleIncrement = (index) => new Promise(resolve => {
   const tempCount =  Object.assign([], this.state.instrumentCOunt);
  // increment the desired instrument
  tempCount[index] += 1;
  // update the state
  this.setState({
    instrumentCount: tempCount
  }, () => resolve(this.state.instrumentCount) ) ;
})

handleDecrement = (index) => new Promise(resolve => {
   const tempCount =  Object.assign([], this.state.instrumentCOunt);
  tempCount[index] -= 1;
  this.setState({
    instrumentCount: tempCount
  }, () => resolve(this.state.instrumentCount) ) ;
})


onClick={ ()=> {
   this.handleIncrement(1)
    .then(()=>  this.handleDecrement(0) )
}}
```

or using await

```
onClick={async ()=> {
  await  this.handleIncrement(1)
  this.handleDecrement(0) 
}}
```